# How to allow my app to run always in background in user's phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using Firebase cloud messaging (FCM) to send notification in my app but whenever I close my app and remove it from my recent apps(completely closing the application) I am not able to get those notification.I only get notifications when my app is already running in background and I have not completely killed the application.
So how to make my app always run in background so that I can receive each and every notification

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be that your device treats "remove it from my recent apps" as doing the same as "Force Stop" in the Settings app. If so, there is nothing that you can do about it. Most device models do not behave that way, and your app should be able to continue to receive FCM messages even after its process is terminated. Note, though, that power conservation steps may slow down FCM messages on newer Android versions.

Comment: I am using OnePlus 7 device (Android 10) and when I  kill my app I am not able to get the notification and the notification never comes even after a whole day

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [Android Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). It is explained with example in Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Notification service and for your app and add the same in your manifest file. 
Check the android documentation.
However, one thing needs to be noted - in many Chinese manufactured phones (Xiaomi, Lenovo) when you kill an app, it stops the background services of it. However, you can bypass this by changing battery optimization for your app from the settings.